# Transferring data from open excel sheet to Access VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

We have an excel template that is provided to us, and part of our process is to load all variations of this template into an access database to easier review the data. We have built a macro within the access database to help us with verifying all the data on a large scale.

The macro current opens the excel file, loops through and recalculates based on different parameters, then saves the file and transfers it to the database. I keep the file open until all transfers are done to save on network time.

I am currently accomplishing this via the code below, but am getting an undesired result, the insert call into access opens another excel instance with a read only version of the same file. It doesnt appear to do anything else later with this file. Any ideas as to this behavior? Or is there a better way for me to be doing this, given the excel file is already open? Thanks!!!

**Edit: This actually doesn't work as I hoped. The second instance that opens up never changes, and it appears that the JET insert statement keeps referencing the read only file, not the excel instance i have open.**

Jay

```
Sub enumerateForm()

'Create Excel application
Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
appExcel.Visible = True

'Open Form Template
wbFormTemplate = "7.31 Form 2017EY.xlsm"
Dim wbbasefile As Excel.Workbook
Set wbbasefile = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(wbFormTemplate, True, False)

 'Dim wsctrl As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim rsCubeFilters As DAO.Recordset

 Dim Cube1Val(1 To 111) As String
 Dim Cube2Val(1 To 111) As String
 Dim Cube1filter As String
 Dim cube2filter As String
 Dim filterSheet As String

'Set recordsets for the loops. This is grabbing all the pivot filters for the enumeration process
Set rsCubeFilters = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Cube1Values] WHERE [Filing] = 'HHS'")


'Loops through all Enumerations
Do While rsCubeFilters.EOF = False
    'Empty the array for the cube filter
    Erase Cube1Val
    Erase Cube2Val
    filterSheet = "Pt 1 Summary of Data"

    'Cube 1 Filter Update (Situs State)
    Cube1filter = rsCubeFilters(1).Value
    wbbasefile.Sheets(filterSheet).PivotTables(filterSheet).PivotFields(Cube1filter).ClearAllFilters
    wbbasefile.Sheets(filterSheet).PivotTables(filterSheet).CubeFields(37).EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    Cube1Val(1) = rsCubeFilters(2).Value
    wbbasefile.Sheets(filterSheet).PivotTables(filterSheet).PivotFields(Cube1filter).VisibleItemsList = Array(Cube1Val)

    'Cube 2 Filter Update (Legal Entity)
    cube2filter = rsCubeFilters(3).Value
    wbbasefile.Sheets(filterSheet).PivotTables(filterSheet). _ 
PivotFields(cube2filter).ClearAllFilters
wbbasefile.Sheets(filterSheet).PivotTables(filterSheet) _
.CubeFields(11).EnableMultiplePageItems = True
Cube2Val(1) = rsCubeFilters(4).Value
wbbasefile.Sheets(filterSheet).PivotTables(filterSheet).PivotFields(cube2filter).VisibleItemsList = Array(Cube2Val)

'Refresh All Cubes
appExcel.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
wbbasefile.RefreshAll
appExcel.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone

wbbasefile.Save

Dim rsExcelRanges As DAO.Recordset
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection

Set rsExcelRanges = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Excel Ranges] WHERE [Filing] = 'HHS'")
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 ssql = "INSERT INTO [" & rsExcelRanges(3).Value & "] "
  ssql = ssql & "SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & wbFormTemplate & "].[" & rsExcelRanges(1).Value & "$" & rsExcelRanges(2).Value & "]"

  CurrentDb.Execute ssql

rsCubeFilters.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: The JET SQL statement where you reference a connection string to the excel file is indeed opening a new instance to read from. This is opening in Read Only because you already opened the file at the start of the code and you never closed it. I would add a line of code to close the file after you've done all the checks in the first half of your function.

Answer (score 0):

After your code is done validating the excel file and saves it, you would then need to close the file to release it for editing. Just add a few lines of code to close out the workbook and quit the excel application. Then your query will open the file read-write.

```
...
'Refresh All Cubes
appExcel.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
wbbasefile.RefreshAll
appExcel.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone

wbbasefile.Save
wbbasefile.Close
appExcel.quit 

Dim rsExcelRanges As DAO.Recordset
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection

Set rsExcelRanges = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Excel Ranges] WHERE [Filing] = 'HHS'")
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
...
```

Comment: its not the most feasible option. I would have to reopen the file (for every iteration), and that really slows down the process.

Comment: I can see what you mean. The issue still stands that your SQL statement is what causes the second instance to open. Maybe you could consider changing the INSERT statement to not reference the file. Since you have the file open, you could read in the values one by one (not sure how many columns you have). So you would have instead of `"INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM..."` You would do something like `"INSERT INTO ... VALUES(" & wbbasefile.[YourRANGE1].value & ", " & wbbasefile.[YourRANGE2].value & ", " ...  & wbbasefile.[YourRANGEn].value & ")"`

Comment: I had considered using something like a recordset. but it would make the code uglier and potentially slow things down further than just reopening the sheet each time. There are multiple sheets in different formats, hence using the recordset data to identify what range to pull.